# How can I Run a 230V 50hz tool on 100V 60hz

Tags: electrical

I have a drilling machine bought in England which I want to use in Japan. I believe I will need some kind of inverter. Suggestions for the cheapest way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "100V"?

Comment: Japan has 2 pin 100V similar to 2 wire outlets of old in the U.S. depending where you are the frequency is 50Hz eastern / northern, 60Hz southern and both in some areas.

Comment: Would it be possible to do 100V the way you would do 220V in the US?  For 110V, we have a hot and neutral.  For 220v, we use 2 hots on opposite phases.  I do not know if 200V will be sufficient for your tool.  Is there a transformer in the drill that could be replaced?  These would be more permanent solutions, not sure how permanent your solution needs to be.

Comment: @rpmperf: 200V is outside the normal +10%/-6% tolerance  for UK  "230V" appliances =  216 - 253 VAC.

Answer (score 1):

Most motors will run on 50 & 60 Hz so you need a step up transformer to run a 230v tool on 100.
Here is [step up/down](https://www.zoro.com/dayton-step-updown-voltage-converter-500va-16v986/i/G4652033/?gdffi=047ada998cf641fa93e55ae8579df863&gdfms=DB39432A76B445C3A2AAC30B55FEA15C&gclid=CPyz7oqqyssCFciFfgod5ZcJgw&gclsrc=aw.ds). You will need one large enough to handle the wattage of your drilling machine. When I searched step up transformer there were some as high as 2000W. These get more expensive as the wattage increases. If you go with a step up transformer make sure to get a larger one than you need by at least 10% and 20-30% if you will be using it for long periods of time as they get hot when over loaded.

Comment: I read it backwards will adjust my answer.